# Execute method only once after all changes have happened in Observable in Angular ReplaySubject

Tags: rxjs, angular2-services

I have created a service which checks for changes in parent component and send notifications to the child component.

Below is the simple service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';
import { CloudDate } from './cloudDate';
import { Clouding } from './clouding';

@Injectable()
export class CloudingService {
    // Observable string sources
    private cloudingAnnouncedSource = new ReplaySubject<Clouding>(1);
    private cloudingConfirmedSource = new ReplaySubject<Clouding>(1);

    // Observable string streams
    cloudingAnnounced$ = this.cloudingAnnouncedSource.asObservable();
    cloudingConfirmed$ = this.cloudingConfirmedSource.asObservable();

    // Service message commands
    announceClouding(clouding: Clouding) {
        this.cloudingAnnouncedSource.next(clouding);
    }

    confirmClouding(clouding: Clouding) {
        this.cloudingConfirmedSource.next(clouding);
    }
}
```

Clouding class looks like this:

```
export class Clouding {
    cameraName: string;
    cloudDate: string;
    cameraType: string;
}
```

Now in the parent component, this class is initialized in the constructor and its variables will change depending on different methods.
Example:

```
// In constructor
this.clouding = new Clouding();

// A method
getCameras(): void {
    this.clouding.cameraName = this.currentCloudName;
}

//Another method
getCloudDates(): void {
    this.clouding.cloudDate = this.currentCloudDate.cloudDate;
}
```

The variables this.currentCloudName and this.currentCloudDate.cloudDate will change dynamically depending on button clicks.

When the buttons are clicked, I do:

```
this.cloudingService.announceClouding(this.clouding);
```

In child component, I do this to get the new value of clouding.

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Clouding} from './clouding';
import { CloudingService } from './clouding.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-images',
    templateUrl: './images.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./images.component.css']
})

export class ImagesComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
    title = 'Images';
    @Input()
    clouding: Clouding;
    subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(
        private cloudingService: CloudingService
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subscription = 
           this.cloudingService.cloudingAnnounced$.subscribe(
            clouding => {
                this.clouding = clouding;
                console.log(this.clouding);
            },
            // The 2nd callback handles errors.
            (err) => console.error(err),
            // The 3rd callback handles the "complete" event.
            () => {
            }
        );
        this.cloudingService.confirmClouding(this.clouding);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Now on the console, I get the below when I click on a button in the parent:

```
Clouding {cameraName: "Benjamin2", cloudDate: "2017-08-26"}
Clouding {cameraName: "Benjamin2", cloudDate: "2017-08-24"}
```

My question is, is there a way to make console print only the last change i.e.

```
Clouding {cameraName: "Benjamin2", cloudDate: "2017-08-24"}
```

and ignore the first change that occurred. I dont want to do execute a method everytime the object changes, just execute after all changes have been subscribed.

Hope the question is clear.

Comment: You never actually complete the observable, so: not really, no. You could use `.last` to access the final value before completion, otherwise.

Comment: I have tried that, but when the button is clicked again, nothing is announced.

Comment: Yes, because that can only happen once, that’s the point of completing the stream.

Comment: I see the ReplaySubject buffer size is set to 1, so the problem is that you're getting two items in child subscription when the buffer should drop the old value? See here, https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec/subjects/ReplaySubject-spec.ts, unit test "it('should only replay values within its buffer size'". Perhaps a CodePen would be usefull.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a third button to trigger the announce, take this off the name-setting button and date-setting button and put it on the new button.

```
this.cloudingService.announceClouding(this.clouding);
```